# How can I chnage the relative size of the text inside font-awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

So I wanted to know if it's possible to change the size of the text which is inside the icon. For example- If the icon is like this- [image] then can I change the icon to this?- [image]
Keeping the radius of the circle same. Is this possible?

Comment: add more detail about your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets say you're starting with this icon here:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle-question?s=regular&f=classic

[image: question mark circle]

The way that these icons work, it's like you're using a character in a font.. Like the letter 'i' - you can't change the size of the base of the 'i' without changing the size of the dot on top right?

But you're not out of luck.. In this case, just choose a plain question mark:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/question?s=solid&f=classic

[image: question mark]

And then create the outer circle like this:

```
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#000066;border-radius:25px;">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i>
</div>
```

That's how to get the most flexibility out of your icons!

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it's a **icon** - picture, image. There is no text inside, just pixels.

What you can do with you **awesome** icons:
https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/style/size

Get icon, get graphics editor and edit it to whatever you want. Oops, you already did it.